# How to use Vue 3 reactive object outside Vue ecosystem

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs3, micro-frontend

I'm trying to pass global state created like this in micro front end applications. But the problem is that I have to "watch" for changes somehow in order to setState for example in a React app.

globalState.js

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const globalState = reactive({
  counter: 0
})

export default globalState
```

In Vue micro front ends im doing this and it is working fine

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

export default (rootEl, globalState) => {
  const app = createApp(App)
  app.config.globalProperties.globalState = globalState
  app.mount(rootEl)
}
```

However in a React app I pass the reference correctly but when counter value changes I have to somehow detect it and call setState in order to rerender the change. The Question is how can I watch for changes of this reactive object reference outside Vue ecosystem.

Comment: You don't need Vue in order to create and use reactive objects in React - simply use the Proxy API (https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-proxy/)

Comment: yeah but vue reactive already does it for me I was hoping to have API to somehow watch the changes outside vue. Otherwise ill probably use rxjs or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Reactivity API](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) is available as standalone libraries (separate from the `vue` package) that can be used outside the context of Vue.

[`@vue/reactivity`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/reactivity) includes [`reactive()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive)/[`ref()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref). And [`@vue-reactivity/watch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue-reactivity/watch) includes [`watch()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch)/[`watchEffect()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect).

For example, you could use a `watchEffect` (or `watch`) to log the new value of `globalState.counter` and display it in an element on the page:

```js
// main.js
import { watchEffect } from '@vue-reactivity/watch'
import globalState from './globalState'

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('counter', globalState.counter)
  document.querySelector('#count').innerHTML = globalState.counter
})
```

```js
// globalState.js
import { reactive } from '@vue/reactivity'

const globalState = reactive({
  counter: 0
})

export default globalState
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-reactivity-outside-apps?file=main.js)

In a React app, you could use a `watch` to log the new value of `globalState.counter` and then call a component's `setState()` to re-render the component:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { watch } from '@vue-reactivity/watch'
import globalState from './globalState'
import GlobalCounterButton from './GlobalCounterButton'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unwatch = watch(
      () => globalState.counter,
      (newValue, oldValue) => {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          console.log('counter', newValue)
          setCount(newValue)
        }
      }
    )
    return () => unwatch()
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalCounterButton />
      <h2>count is: {count}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-reactivity-in-react-app-wddxb7?file=src%2FApp.jsx)